# what is instancing in blender

Tags: objects

When we create a new object in Blender, we say we instantiate an object, this is true when we hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> as well. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> means a linked duplicate, which means we create a new object with one of the previously available data blocks. But, I'm not particularly sure what  this word 'instancing' in [this website](http://thilakanathanstudios.com/2014/11/6-ways-to-reduce-memory-when-using-blender/) really means. It says it helps save a lot of memory, but yet, it is  different from creating linked instances or even creating dupliverts as they have points of their own. So, what is this **instancing** [as mentioned in this site.](http://thilakanathanstudios.com/2014/11/6-ways-to-reduce-memory-when-using-blender/)

Comment: May I point you to here - the topic has to many variations as to explained just in one textbox:
[Blender Manual about Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/index.html) The provided links of that page give a better explanation about one can do with instances.

Comment: I would ask this question on the page it self. I has a commentary function and if I where the author I would like to know if there was any unclarity on the content so that I could fix it for all readers.

Comment: I think the word is used for different things: linked duplications / particles / dupliverts / group instances (or collection instances in 2.8)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bunch of definitions for **Instance**. The article you mention use the definition: **Make it duplicate when in rendering pipeline**

Instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, instancing will not likely directly been manipulated by user. E.g. you won't <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for 1000 trees in a mountain, you will rather use particle system to plant instances for you, with some weight control or random method.

But if you want to place three identical boxes in specified places, you will want to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for actually manipulate the position for boxes.

They are similar concept but with different strategy. Depends on how you want to use them.

#### Other Instances

**Instance** is a common computer terminology that indicate we make something actually exist in memory and scene or workspace.

In Unity, instantiating an object mean to make a copy from its resources. Which might be totally as same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Blender. In Python or other OOP, all objects you manipulate are an instance from their class. Also, **instance** might mean to separate some minimum attribute to make it more easily to manipulate without having a full copy.

Comment: by: "making it duplicate when in rendering pipeline" do you mean: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/faces.html#basic-usage , this is the step to do the `instancing`, mentioned in the link I provided? And does it help save memory as mentioned?

Comment: They could all been called **instancing**. Yes, for the most simplest thing, geometry vertices is the same thing with one memory copy. For sure they save memory by having some structure data shared by all instancing. eg. the 1000 trees only need **1 mesh** data **1 material** data and **1000 tuples of transform** data. Those mesh data can be very large in some cases.

Comment: And for that article, **instancing** means all of them in that Blender page. `alt+D` is a similar concept, the code behind it should be almost the same. It just the method different, they all save memory by having the same copy of some duplicated data.